# Android Square Register - card option not appearing

Tags: android, square-connect

manually When I log into the Square Register app on my device and do a sale, I get the options of "Record Card Payment", "Cash" and "Other". But when I try to launch via my app, I only get the "Cash" and "Other" options.

I have set the tender types in my app like this:

```
Set<ChargeRequest.TenderType> tenderTypes = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        tenderTypes.add(ChargeRequest.TenderType.CARD);
        tenderTypes.add(ChargeRequest.TenderType.CASH);
        tenderTypes.add(ChargeRequest.TenderType.OTHER);
```

..so why does the card option not appear?

The card option does appear if I don't set any tender types - i.e., by not calling `restrictTendersTo(tenderTypes)`.

I am wondering why this is. And how to set it up so the user is only presented with Cash and Card options when coming via my app?

NB - I don't have an actual card reader attached to my device yet.

Comment: Which version of Android are you on?

Comment: Also which country are you trying the requests from?

Comment: My device is running Android 5.0.2 and I'm in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Square's APIs are not currently available in every country. (Right now only US & Canada) See here https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/faq-international-availability/

Comment: Can you advise when the APIs will be available in UK and in Australia? Also, can you advise why the card option is shown if I don't call `restrictTendersTo(tenderTypes)`?

Comment: We don't have a public timeline for API availability in the UK or Australia, but it is something we are actively working on. We are investigating `restrictTendersTo` functionality you found. Could you share the version of the Square Register app you are using?